# Unable to set the background color of the GraphicsView control

Tags: colors, background, controls, maui

Unable to change background color of GraphicsView control.  I can change the background color of the ContentPage, but the background color of the GraphicsView assumes the color of the ContentPage.  I tried to ensure the opacity of the GraphicsView is set to 1.  I even tried to set the background color in the code behind.  Even A.I. is failed me.  It is giving me solutions that have nothing to do with GraphicsView.  Microsoft examples on GraphicsView or canvas don’t change the background color.  Any help please.

[image: Backgrouind color of GraphicsView not changing color to yellow]

**XAML**

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Border StrokeThickness="0">
        <GraphicsView x:Name="canvas" 
                      Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
                      HeightRequest="500"
                      WidthRequest="500"
                      Background="Yellow"
                      BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
    </Border>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

**C# Code Behind**

```
public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
    canvas.FontColor = Colors.Red;
    canvas.FontSize = 18;
    canvas.DrawString("Text is left aligned.", 50, 20, 380, 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment.Top);
    canvas.DrawString("Text is centered.", 20, 60, 380, 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Top);
    canvas.DrawString("Text is right aligned.", 20, 100, 380, 100, HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment.Top);
    canvas.FillColor = Colors.Yellow;
    canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Android at least on .NET 8, I have even raised a bug for the same that you can find in their Github repo https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19568

Comment: I found Windows has the same issue.  I did figure out using a Frame control around the GraphicsView, and setting the background color of the Frame control will get the results I want.  I did not have to adjust the opacity or zindex.  This works for Android and Windows.

Comment: Frame is deprecated control in maui in my opinion just use a ContentView

Comment: I took your advice and created a custom control for GraphicsView control so I could change the background color.  That required a lot of code.  It did force me to start learning custom controls though.  Not impressed with the complexity.  I'm sticking with my Frame control option for new because I'm sure Microsoft will fix this issue by next week.  Ha Ha Ha!!!  Thanks.

Comment: All I meant was to use ContentView/Border  instead of Frame, I did not mean create a custom control lol

Comment: I'm confused.  A ContentView/Border is a custom control unless I haven't learned something yet.  Anyway, when I first ran into this problem, I tried the Border control and it didn't have a BackgroundColor property.  I just tried it again and now Border control does have a BackgroundColor property.  Go figure.  Sorry for wasting your time although I do appreciate the help.

Comment: Why don't you show me what you have done and i can help you update it

Comment: Problem solved. I figured out how to change the background color of the GraphicsView control without having to use a Frame control or a ContentView.

Comment: I used the border control.  For some strange reason the first time I tried the border control, before posting this question, it didn't work.  After posting this question I tried to use the border control again and hit had a BackgroundColor property.  My typing must have been way off.